# Difference between Processor and ScriptProcessor in AWS Sagemaker SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

From [Sagemaker python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) I have seen two API, [ScriptProcessor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.ScriptProcessor) and [Processor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.Processor). It seems like we can achieve the same goals using either of them, the only difference I noticed ScriptProcessor support docker `command` parameter on the other hand Processor support docker `entrypoint` parameter. Is there any other difference amongst them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sagemaker.processing.ScriptProcessor` subclasses `sagemaker.processing.Processor`. `ScriptProcessor` can be used to write a custom processing script. `Processor` can be subclassed to create a `CustomProcessor` class for a more complex use case.